# Solution to matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have row vector $x=[a,b,c]$ with length 3, the 3 by 3 matrix $M=\pmatrix{M_{11} & M_{12} & M_{13} \cr M_{21} & M_{22} & M_{23} \cr M_{31} & M_{32} & M_{33} \cr}$ and 3 by 3 matrix $X=x^T*x$) which combined give vector $y=[abc,bc,c]$. How do I solve this equation? $xMX=y$

or
$$[a,b,c]\pmatrix{M_{11} & M_{12} & M_{13} \cr M_{21} & M_{22} & M_{23} \cr M_{31} & M_{32} & M_{33} \cr}\pmatrix{aa & ab & ac \cr ab & bb & cb \cr ac & bc & cc \cr}=[abc,bc,c]$$

or

$$[aM_{11}+bM_{12}+cM_{13},aM_{21}+bM_{22}+cM_{23},aM_{31}+bM_{32}+cM_{33}]\pmatrix{aa & ab & ac \cr ab & bb & cb \cr ac & bc & cc \cr}=[abc,bc,c]$$

My actual goal is to go from $x$ to $y$ through linear algebra. We came up with this matrix multiplication. Now I want to solve for M and I am not sure how to approach this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find xMX.
You'll get 9 terms in every column.

Among 9 terms of first column, coefficient of term containing abc will be 1(because in result,only abc is there, & its coef is 1), while all other coefficients will be zero.

For 2nd column, coef of bc will be 1, rest all coef will be zero, & for 3rd column, coef of c will be 1, rest all coef will be zero.

So, in total, you'll get 27 equations. Solve them & you'll get all 9 values of M.

Comment: thanks for your help! However the matrix resulting from MX has two a or b or c terms so when taking the product with x then gives three terms in each column for Y. Does this mean it is not possible to get y from x?

Comment: $[a,b,c]\pmatrix{
aam_{11}+abm_{12}+acm_{13} , abm_{11}+bbm_{12}+bcm_{13} , acm_{11}+cbm_{12}+cc_{m13} \cr

aam_{21}+abm_{22}+acm_{23} , abm_{21}+bbm_{22}+bcm_{23} , acm_{21}+cbm_{22}+cc_{m23} \cr

aam_{31}+abm_{32}+acm_{33} , abm_{31}+bbm_{32}+bcm_{33} , acm_{31}+cbm_{32}+cc_{m33} \cr
}=[abc,bc,c]$

Comment: Maybe using $z=\frac{1}{x}=[\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c}]$ and $N=z^T*z$ in combination with $M$ to get rid of the extra termns? No wait then everywhere you put a $1$ in $N$ it would get rid of three terms just like $M$ creates three. Darn. Dont know whether this is hard or not possible.

Comment: Or maybe different steps instead of one $M$ for the whole selection?

Comment: First get a matrix with all triples, a matrix with all doubles and a matrix with the singles of $x$ then a linear combination of those terms into then with a inproduct collapse the triples matrix into $[abc,0,0]$, collapse the matrix with doubles into $[0,bc,0]$ and collapse the singles matrix into $[0,0,c]$ ?

Comment: $$y=\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3$$
$$\gamma_1=Ix\pmatrix{0,0,0\cr0,0,1\cr0,0,0}x^Tx\pmatrix{1\cr0\cr0}=[abc,0,0]$$
$$\gamma_2=Ix^Tx\pmatrix{0\cr0\cr1}\pmatrix{0\cr1\cr0}=[0,bc,0]$$
$$\gamma_3=Ix\pmatrix{0\cr0\cr1}=[0,0,c]$$
Not the most general answer yet, could be all square matrices instead of base vectors and then use i for dimension or length so its a general answer... I think there should be brackets in there as well. hmm lemme check

Comment: I couldnt understand your problem. However, you multiply any two of those 3 matrices first, you'll get same answer, & in any case, it'll be a 1X3 matrix